# Asp.net Core spa + angular4 + firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, asp.net-core

How can i include firebase in asp.net core spa application, i have install firebase from node "npm install angularfire2 firebase --save" but when i run the application it gives me an error on vendor, how to slove this error?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase offers FirebaseAdmin SDK for .Net. It is a community maintained SDK. Not all features are available for .Net.
Refer the below blog for implementing push notifications using Firebase in an ASP.Net application.
https://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/sending-push-notifications-from-asp-net-core-using-google-firebase